# mySQL DBA Software

Tags: mysql, database-administration

Are the free mySQL GUI tools adequate for administering a mySQL db running 'vendor' supplied applications?

Are there other tools you would recommend that make your life easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's:

- [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net) - been around for
  ages & packed with features
- [SQLYog](http://www.webyog.com) - which used to be open source, but now offers a 'community edition'

There's also [MySQL Administrator](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) which is provided by mysql although I've never used it.

Other tools:
For backup:

- [zmanda](http://www.zmanda.com/backup-mysql.html) offer a community version backup tool
- xtrabackup as mentioned by pQd is fantasic & open source

Answer (score 3):

i'm surprised [maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/) was not mentioned yet. it does not provide any fancy gui applications, instead it gives dba set of command line tools that can be used to analyze mysql logs, diff and synchronize content of databases, run faster database dumps [ by executing parallel queries  ]. you can read more [here](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/).

another useful tool - [xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtrabackup:start) - free & open source hot backup of innodb databases.

Comment: yes xtrabackup! I've heard its awesome, i couldnt remember the name

Answer (score 1):

[Navicat for MySQL](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql) (there are also Oracle and PostgreSQL versions too). Not free though. US$179 for the downloadable version ($189 for the CD). Highly recommended for all MySQL DBAs and developers using MySQL.

There is a [trial version](https://www.navicat.com/en/download/navicat-for-mysql) available as well.

Answer (score 1):

Propably look into:

[HeidiSQL](http://HeidiSQL) - made my life easier

and

[MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Answer (score 1):

[PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is a great tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use :
[Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com)
or
[SQL Manager](http://www.sqlmanager.net)
or
[MySQL Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com)